# JavaScript works under Firefox but does not work under IE

Tags: javascript, html

I am having the following HTML file protected through JavaScript.

It works fine with Firefox, howover, when it is opened with IE, the JavaScript seems not get invoked. The grading.pdf is directly displayed after clicking the hyperlink.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>JavaScript Example 8</TITLE>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--------

var password;

 var pass1="test";

 password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');

 if (password==pass1)
     alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');
 else
    {
    window.location="jpass.htm";
     }

 //----------->
</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

 <BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

 <!--<H1 align="center"><a href="grades.pdf">grading</a></H1>-->

 <CENTER>
 <!--<A HREF="grades.htm">Grading</A>-->
<a href="grades.pdf">grading</a>
```

Comment: My comment is not related directly to your question... But to me, password with javascript is easy to crack. Only have to do "View Source" and you have the password. Wouldn't it be safer to use a server side password protection? Otherwise, there's something I'm missing.

Comment: To be sure, please, *please*, don't confuse [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) with [JavaServer Pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages). That are two entirely different things. I removed the JSP tag.

Comment: password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' '), seeing this code i think you should put '' instead ' ' because in your prompt it will have a default one leading whitespace and the user may not see the leading whitespace if he/she type a password.. other way is to trim the entered password..

Comment: This "password protection" sucks big time, and is as secure as putting a "please don't break in" sign on an unlocked door. While it's an interesting question why it doesn't work in IE (I don't see any reason for it) You should not be using it.

Comment: Not only is it ridiculously easy to crack, having the default behaviour be to see the 'secured' content, and the non-default (else-clause) to navigate away is even worse.  Disabling javascript will allow the user in.  Even if the system works, you're navigating away using window.location, so the user can still see a flash of the content.

Security must be on the server, not on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE 8 and above makes **prompt** an unsafe method, which may be ignored or called with a security confirmation, as set in advanced properties of IE by the user. (IE uses activeX in window.prompt)

Security updates may also apply this behavior to IE7.

Get the input from an input field instead of a prompt, at least in IE.