# Javascript not work in IE browser, but work fine for firefox or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, password-protection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript works under Firefox but does not work under IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553143/javascript-works-under-firefox-but-does-not-work-under-ie)

The script below is not working for IE. Don't worry about whether it's secure or not, I just want to test this javascript but I have no idea why it's not working on IE. When I open it on IE, it will treat it as wrong password and go to the google page straight away. The alert for entering the password is not executed. However, it's working fine for other browsers. I have tried many different version of IE and disabled the block add-on but still no luck to make it work.

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--hide

var password;

var pass1="cool";

password=prompt('Please enter your password to view this page!',' ');

if (password==pass1)
  alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');
else
   {
    window.location="http://www.google.com/";
    }

//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not removing the default space you have in the prompt when using IE?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in FF, Chrome and IE8. IE just complains about some security stuff but if allowed, work fine.

Comment: This is just a variation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553143/javascript-works-under-firefox-but-does-not-work-under-ie

Comment: @David indeed, same exact script :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in IE6 and IE8, although I do receive a security warning in both that I have to click through.

If you add the line

```
window.alert('received password: ' + password);
```

directly under the prompt line, what do you see as the password? Does this shed any light on the problem?

Also, where are you running this from (file/web server) and what is Internet Explorer reporting as the security zone (on bar at the bottom of the browser, towards the right - probably says something line Internet or Local Intranet or something)?

**[EDIT - in response to comment from OP]**

You've just revealed you are running this on the *server*. On Windows 2008 servers (possibly 2003 - can't remember), Internet Explorer runs in something called Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Mode (it probably says this on its "home page" when you start it up). In this mode, security is ultra tight and it won't run Javascript and lots of other stuff from anything but trusted sites, and it won't even warn you. This is to limit the chance you can accidentally introduce a virus, trojan or whatever to your server just by web browsing form it. The behaviour you describe now makes *total* sense.

Unfortunately, I don't think you can add local files to the list of trusted sites (Tools->Internet Options -> Security) so there is no simple way of allowing this file.

You choices are:

- Disable Internet Explorer Enhanced Security. Possibly not recommended, unless you do it for a non-privileged user only.
- Serve this file via the web server on your server, not directly from the file - then you can debug it up over http which you *can* add to the trusted sites list.
- Don't try and debug this stuff on the server at all (at least, not in IE on the server).

Comment: Just tried adding your script, but make nothing different. on my IE8, it just have no chance to enter the password, and go straight to the wrong password page -  google.com. any other thing I can try please?

Comment: so you didn't receive a popup saying "received password"? My gut feeling is this is likely to be one of two things. Either there is some IE blocker or security restriction, *or* there is a JavaScript error on the page. Is the code you posted the entire page, or is it a snippet from the page? Secondly, where are you running this from - is it a file on your local machine, on a network drive or is it being served up by a web server?

Comment: HI Rob, no, it didn't give a chance to enter or show received password on my IE8. it just go to the google page that on the wrong password condition. I run it from a web server. it looks work fine when I run it from local machine. please check the link: http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test3.html. many thanks

Comment: This is almost certainly a security thing when run locally. Are you not getting a popup warning? Usually, if you run a web page containing JavaScript from your hard disk, you get a warning appear at the top of the page and you have to "allow" content before the JavaScript will run, otherwise it is blocked. It sounds like that is what is happening here, are you seeing the warning? If not, I suspect you may have a security setting to say "don't show warning". Let me know if you get a warning. If not I'll dig around to see if I can find out why not.

Comment: Hi Rob, if I run it locally, it will got the message: "to help protect your security, internet explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts and ActiveX controls. Click here for options." but I couldn't get this message when run it on hosting server, like the link I gave you on last message. don't know why, and I didn't change any setting on my IE. Do you think I can do something on the script? cheers

Comment: see edit above for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page:

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Working_around_IE7s_prompt_bug,_er_feature

EDIT: If that doesn't help, take a look at jQuery. There is a plugin specifically to replace that prompt and avoid IE7 issues (so they say, at least):

http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

jQuery will solve many of the cross-browser compatibility issues of which your post is an example. I resisted it myself for some time, but now I'm glad I started using it.

EDIT 2: This will work in IE7 (no prompt, though)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkPasswd() {
        var passwd = document.getElementById ("passwd");
        if (passwd.value === "cool1")
            alert('Password Correct! Click OK to enter!');
        else
            window.location="http://www.google.com/";
    }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input name="passwd" id="passwd" type="password"/>
            <input name="submit" type="button" value="submit" onclick="checkPasswd();"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 - Or if it's just for his own machine: http://geekswithblogs.net/bbastiaensen/archive/2009/03/19/using-javascript-prompt-in-ie7.aspx - Public sites ought to use HTML form fields really...

Comment: @Lee nice link, although if it's his machine, he should just ditch ie7 asap ;)

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your information, you got any example that work fine on IE7+ then? I really can't work out how can make it work in IE, as the prompt message is never pop up in IE at all no matter how I change the script. many thanks!

Comment: There is a workaround in the same post. Get it here: http://www.hunlock.com/examples/IEprompt.zip

Comment: thanks again, thats I already tried but still nothing respond in IE. cheers

Comment: @xuanyinwen check the two options I added to the answer. I tested the second in ie7 and works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Google the [IE7 prompt bug](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/ie7_javascript_prompt%28%29_alternative.xml) which is probably what you're experiencing.

Comment: I can change the setting of my IE7, but how can i change the setting of the visitor of my webpage then? any idea what other ways I can try pls?